# Validating React-Bootstrap-Typeahead input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I am using a **validation** function in my form, that checks whether a field is **empty** or not. This works for normal text input boxes, but not for the Typeahead box.

I want to check if the Typeahead box is *empty*, and if it is, display an error message i.e. `this.state.industryError`

This is my state:

```
state = {
 name: "",
 industry: [],
 nameError: "",
 industryError: "",
}
```

And this is my Typeahead form element:

```
<Form>
 <Label>Industry</Label>
  <Typeahead
   id="industryMultiSelect"
   multiple
   options={industries}
   placeholder="Select industry..."
   onChange={this.handleTypeaheadChangeIndustry} />
    <div>
     {this.state.industryError}      // Where the error message appears
    </div>
</Form>
```

My validate function is as follows:

```
validate = () => {
    let nameError = "";
    let industryError = "";

    if(!this.state.name) {                  // Checks if field is empty
      nameError = "Please enter a name";
    }

    if(this.state.industry === []) {     // I think this is the problem
      industryError = "Please enter an industry";
    }

    if (nameError || industryError) {
      this.setState({nameError, industryError});

      return false;
    }
      return true;
  };
```

This is `handleChange` function I call for the typeahead:

```
handleTypeaheadChangeIndustry = selected => {
    const industry = selected.map(option => option.value);
    this.setState({industry})
  };
```

It works fine with the `name` field because it equals an empty string. But with the Typeahead, it's not a string, and so I'm unsure what to set `this.state.industry` to.

Any help or advice is much appreciated, and I can quickly update my answer if you need more detail.

Comment: Try this - `if(this.state.industry.length === 0)`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but the problem is it always displays the error message - when the input is empty and when it is not. It's a step in the right direction though, so thank you.

Comment: This is because of `if (nameError || industryError) {` when nameError is true it will set both the values. You need if-else here.

Comment: I don't think it is, because when I remove `nameError` completely, I still get the same problem. And when I include `nameError` the message (for name) is removed once a value is entered, but the message is always there for `industryError`, so I think it is more to do with the fact that even when a value is selected for industry, the length still seems to be 0

Comment: Can you post the code for `this.handleTypeaheadChangeIndustry`?

Comment: @ericgio I have added the requested code

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to pinpoint why your code isn't working without seeing everything. That said, I created a sandbox which I believe does what you're after using the code you posted above:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-typeahead-form-validation-686qe

As @ravibagul91 notes, you should be using one of

```
if (this.state.industry.length === 0) { ... }
if (!this.state.industry.length) { ... }
```

rather than

```
if (this.state.industry === []) { ... }
```

Using the latter in the sandbox I posted causes the code not to work, while things work fine when using either of the first two.